# Why header is bigger than 870px?

Tags: html, css

I have the following page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li class="products">
                    <a href="products.html">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li class="resume">
                    <a href="resume.html">My resume</a>
                </li>
                <li class="blog">
                    <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li class="about">
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Index.css:

```
#page {
    width: 1024px;
    height: 900px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#header {
    width:870px;
}

#menu {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    clear: both;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 20px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 11px 0 11px 34px;
    width: 870px;
}

#menu li {
    float: left;
}

#main {

}

#footer {
    width:870px:
}
```

Common.css:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Testing it with Firebug, I see `#header` is 870px, but `#menu` is bigger that `#header`.

I have disabled margin and padding from menu style, with the same result.

Why `#menu` is bigger that 870px?

I want that border lines have 870px length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `#menu` which is contained inside it has

1. `width` of 870 pixels
2. `padding-left` of 34 pixels

this adds to 870 + 34 = 904 pixels.

setting width of the `#menu` element to 870 - 34 = 836 pixels (`width:836px;`) will make it fit exactly..

Comment: But then there is the 2px from the borders which should be taken into consideration, pushing the width out another 2px. Borders are always outside except for on tables.

Comment: @rickyduck, he has only defined top/bottom borders.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#menu {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    clear: both;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 20px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 11px 0 11px 34px;
    width: 870px;
}
```

is 36px bigger than 870px. Set `width` to `834px` in `#menu`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where does these 36px come from?

Comment: You have padding-right of 34px and then a border-left and border-right of 1px;

Comment: As @Gaby aka G. Petrioli pointed out, it should in fact be `34px` as the border is only applicable to top and bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Because it has padding. The padding will add an additional 34px to your width. If you want the menu to be 870px you'd have to change the width to 836px.

If you alter `#menu` to these properties, you'll have what you want.

```
#menu {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
  border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
  clear: both;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 11px 0 11px 34px;
  width: 836px;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The width you set is like an item in a box.  You have the width of the content (which corresponds to the width you set), then the padding, then the border (the box), then the margin.  In the above code, you've set padding and a border, both of which will add to the visible size of the element.

Answer (score 1):

`#menu` is **Not** bigger that 870px, it is equal as demanded.

`ul` has a padding.

Add `padding-left: 0;` to your `#menu` CSS or reduce the `#menu` width.

Comment: @rickyduck He declares `padding: 11px 0 11px 34px;` so `padding-left:34px`. Needs to `padding-left: 0;` to #menu CSS or reduce the #menu width